# How to create a custom keyboard to use by default on all inputs in the application?

Tags: java, android, mobile, mobile-development

Is there any way how to create my own custom keyboard only for my application (not system keyboard), without the need for the user to change the keyboards in settings and without the need for me to specify for every `EditText` to use the keyboard?

Basically what I am trying to find is a way how to tell my application to use the custom keyboard by default.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way how to create my own custom keyboard only for my application (not system keyboard), without the need for the user to change the keyboards in settings and without the need for me to specify for every EditText to use the keyboard?

No, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Their is no any way to create a custom keyboard for your application ,Rather if you want to take some specific input from user then you can create some buttons on your layout and take input from their.